# How to split list without including brackets, commas, and quotations

Tags: list, split

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31zup.png)

When I split my list, the commas, quotes, and brackets that are next to words get split with them. How can I take my list of sentences, and split them into words without the aformentioned characters?

Want individual words, got commas, quotes, and brackets attached to my words

Comment: Please post code as text, not an image of text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In line 2 you are turning the entire list into a string, including commas and quotation marks. Instead, I would try to put them all in in a string that has the words from all sentences in it but no quotation marks or commas. I would just do something like this to get 'strsent':

```
# declare your sentences list here
strsent = ' '.join(sentences)
split = strsent.split()
# the rest of your code after line 4 would be the same
```

And if you really want to simplify all of your code, you can do this:

```
sentences = [] # add your own sentences here
strsent = ' '.join(sentences)
split = strsent.split()
unique_words = sorted(set(split))
print(unique_words)
```

Let me know if this helps or if you have any more questions!